# Laravel Date Group By date and count

Tags: sql, laravel

i have table 'country_visit' like this

```
City     | Created_at
-------------------------------
Jakarta  | 2018-11-15 06:27:22
Jakarta  | 2018-11-12 05:25:24
Jakarta  | 2018-11-11 05:27:23
Jakarta  | 2018-11-15 07:27:22
Denpasar | 2018-11-15 05:27:22
Denpasar | 2018-11-12 05:27:22
Makassar | 2018-11-15 05:27:22
Makassar | 2018-11-11 05:27:22
Makassar | 2018-11-12 05:27:22
```

I need result like this

```
City     | dateis    | total
-------------------------------
Jakarta  | 15 Nov    | 2
Jakarta  | 12 Nov    | 1
Jakarta  | 11 Nov    | 1
```

I was success when use SQL like this

```
SELECT city,DATE_FORMAT(created_at,"%d %b") AS dateis, COUNT(city) AS total
FROM country_visit
WHERE city = 'Jakarta'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

How that query equivalent with Laravel queries ?
Btw i still using Laravel 5.4

Comment: is laravel a data entity framework? laravel seems php based which is independent of backend data access and thus you should keep separate from or at least modularize. you have sql that works, create a class that passes that data to the front

Comment: i was tried using db raw, like this DB::select("SELECT city,DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%d %b') AS dateis,COUNT(city) AS total FROM country_visit WHERE city='Jakarta' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d')"); . but still doesnt works

Answer (score 2):

I solve my self

```
select("city",
DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%d %b') AS dateis"),
DB::raw("COUNT(city) AS total"))
->where("city","Jakarta")
->groupby(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d')"))
->get();
```

the key is in

```
config/database.php
```

some setting need to change
from

```
'strict' => true,
```

to

```
'strict' => false,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$table = DB::table('country_visit')
        ->select('city', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
        ->groupBy('dateis')
        ->get();
```

Comment: looks close but they want date too

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'dateis' in 'group statement' (SQL: select `city`, count(*) as total from `country_visit` group by `dateis`)

Comment: @Artron Don't you have a `dateis` column in your table?